# How does the syntax "exp1 << variable << exp2" work in Python?

Tags: python

While I was reading a book, I found this example.

```py
def apply_discount(product, discount):
    price = int(product['price'] * (1.0 - discount))
    assert 0 <= price <= product['price']
    return price
```

I never saw the syntax `0 <= price <= product['price']` before, and it's clear that here it's testing the price, which should `>= 0` and `<= product['price']`. I tested the function and it works as expected. I want to do more testing about the syntax `0 <= price <= product['price']`.

```py
a = 7
if 0 << a << 10:
    print('a is greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10')
else:
    print('a is not greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10')
```

It always prints `a is not greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10`. Why does it happen? What exactly does `0 << a << 10` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` is a shift operator, you need to use `<` or `<=`:

```py
a = 7
if 0 <= a <= 10:
    print('a is greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10')
else:
    print('a is not greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 10')
```

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is a bitwise operation that correspond to a left shift. A left shift is analogous to multiplying by two.

For example:

```py
print(2 << 1)
# 4
print(2 << 2) # Do two left-shifts
# 8
```

In general, `n << m` will be equal to `n * (2 ** m)`.

Now shifting has a left to right associativity so your condition will be interpreted as `((0 << a) << 10)`. Using the formula above, you'll notice that this will always give us `0`, regardless of what the value of `a` is. `0` is equivalent to a boolean `False` so your condition will always be `False`

Answer (score 1):

### Your check uses bit-shifting, *not* comparison operations. It will always produce a [falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/17769815) value.

`<<` is the [left shift operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). It is *not* a comparison operation (use `<` or `<=` if you want comparison).

To see how this expression works, we evaluate the operations left to right. So, `0 << a << 10` is equivalent to `(0 << a) << 10`.

- `(0 << a)` is 0 shifted over `a` bits, which is 0. `a` happens to be 7 here, but shifting 0 over by any number of bits would still produce zero.
- `0 << 10` is 0 shifted over 10 bits, which is still 0.
- Zero is a falsey value, so the `if` check fails, and the `else` branch is executed.